# Is this proposition true for any field

Tags: linear-algebra

The proposition from my text book is as follows:

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a linear transformation on linear space $V$ of field $F$ with $n$ dimension. If the matrix of the linear transformation $\mathscr{A}$ is the same on any basis, then $\mathscr{A}$ can be writen as $kI$,where $k\in F$

Now, if $F$ is a number field, I can transform this problem to discussing the commutativity between matrix $A$ and singular matrix $PA=AP$, and then make the matrices $P$ equal to $diag\left \{ a_1,...a_n \right \} $ and $J_n(k)$ respectively, where $a_i\ne a_j(i\ne j)$. After that, we can obtain $A=kI$.But if $F$ is a finite field, for example $F=\mathbb{Z}_2$, we cannot find $n$ distinct elements in $F$, and the above method will not work.

So, is this proposition true for a finite field?

Ps:$1、J_n(k)=\begin{pmatrix}
  k&  1&  & \\
  &  \ddots&  \ddots& \\
  &  &  \ddots&1 \\
  &  &  &k
\end{pmatrix},k\ne0$

2、The phrase "the matrix $A$ of linear transformation $\mathscr{A}$ on  basis $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$" means
$$
\mathscr{A}(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)=(\mathscr{A}(\alpha_1),...,\mathscr{A}(\alpha_n))=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)A
$$
where $V=\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^n F\alpha_i$ .

Comment: The phrase  "If the matrix of linear transformation  is equal on any basis" makes no sense to me. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @EthanBolker for every basis of a vector space and given any endomorphism, one has an associated matrix representation. The assumption is that there is a single matrix such that for every basis, the matrix representation of the endomorphism is the given matrix, or equivalently for any two bases, the corresponding matrix representations are equal.

Comment: If the characteristic is more than 2, you can just use $diag(1,1,\dots,1,2,1,\dots,1)$ to get that $A$ is diagonal and switch two columns transformations to show it’s a multiple of identity.

Comment: Use matrices of the form $P = I + (V_{n} \otimes V_{m})$ where $n \neq m$. These should be sufficient to cover all the cases.

Comment: Every rank-one square matrix is the difference of two invertible matrices, and every square matrix is the sum of some rank-one matrices. If $A$ commutes with all invertible matrices, it must commute with all square matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not even have to work over a field for this to be true:

Let $M_n(R)$ be the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $R$ a commutative ring (with identity), let $\text{GL}_n(R)$ for the group of units in $M_n(R)$, and set
$$
Z_n(R) = \{A \in M_n(R): P^{-1}AP = A \text{ for all } P \in \text{GL}_n(R)\}.
$$

*Claim*: $Z_n(R) = R.I_n$.

It is clear that $R.I_n \subseteq Z_n(R)$. For the converse, let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix with all entries $0$ except the $(i,j)$ entry, which is equal to $1$. It is easy to check that $E_{ij}E_{kl} 
= \delta_{jk}E_{il}$ where $\delta_{jk}=1$ if $j=k$ and is $0$ otherwise. In particular, if $i \neq j$, $E_{ij}^2=0$.

Now note that if $N\in M_n(R)$ is nilpotent, so that $N^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$, then $I-N \in \text{GL}_n(R)$, where $(I-N)^{-1} = I+N+\ldots+N^{k-1}$. But since, for any $A \in M_n(R)$, $AN=NA$ if and only if $(I-N)A=A(I-N)$ if and only if $A=(I-N)^{-1}A(I-N)$, it follows that if $A \in Z_n(R)$, then $AN=NA$ for all nilpotent $N$. In particular, $AE_{ij} = E_{ij}A$ for all $i \neq j$.

Now if $A = \sum_{k,l} a_{kl}E_{kl}$ we have
$$
E_{ij}A = \sum_{k,l}a_{kl}E_{ij}E_{kl} = \sum_{l} a_{jl}E_{il},\quad AE_{ij} = \sum_{k,l}a_{k,l}E_{kl}E_{ij} = \sum_{k} a_{ki}E_{kj}
$$
hence if $E_{ij}A = AE_{ij}$ we must have $a_{jl}=0$ if $l\neq j$ and $a_{ki} =0$ if $k \neq i$ and $a_{ii} = a_{jj}$. Since this must hold for all $i \neq j$, it follows immediately that $A=a.I_n$.

Comment: Wonderful proof like poetry！I have always wanted to learn how to prove some propositions by discussing the structure of a set. Thank you for your demonstration.